# How do I store user input into database using ASP.NET Core MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I am struggling to find a solution on how to add user input like first name, last name, zipcode.... to the database. The email is already stored in database during signUp.

I tried looking at some resource but they seem complicated.

HomeController

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ProfileView(ApplicationUser users)
{
    return View();
}
```

Application user model:

```
public class ApplicationUser: IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public int ZipCode { get; set; }
}
```

Profile view:

```
<form>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-row col-md-6">
            <div class="col">
                <label for="firstName">First Name:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First name">
            </div>
            <div class="col col-md-6">
                <label for="lastName">Last Name:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last name">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="inputEmail4">Email</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail4" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Database context:

```
public class DataBaseContext: IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{ 
    public DataBaseContext(DbContextOptions<DataBaseContext> options): base(options)
    {
    }

    public new DbSet<SignUp> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Products> Products { get; set; }
}
```

When the user fills out the information in the view it should store it in an existing database.

Comment: It is not clear to me which part of the process you need help with? Your question is too broad. Please narrow down the question to the specific problem that you have. Please refer to tutorials (like [this](https://jonhilton.net/2017/08/17/how-to-get-data-from-an-html-form-to-your-asp.net-mvc-core-controller/)) for an explanation of the whole process.

Comment: I updated the info see if that helps.

Comment: Your form does not have any action. You need to specify an action for your form, which would post back the form the a controller action method and there you need to save the data.

Comment: I put the form action but I still don't know how to store the information

Comment: Have you studied the MVC tutorial provided by Microsoft? It will explain this kind of basic concept

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example on modifying user's profile after logining :

Profile View :

```
@model MVC2_2Project.Models.ApplicationUser

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
    <form id="profile-form" method="post">
        <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="FirstName"></label>
            <input asp-for="FirstName" class="form-control" placeholder="First name"/>
            <span asp-validation-for="LastName" class="text-danger"></span>

        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="LastName"></label>
            <input asp-for="LastName" class="form-control" placeholder="Last name"/>
            <span asp-validation-for="LastName" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <button id="update-profile-button" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
    </form>
</div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
   <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
}
```

HomeController:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public HomeController(
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
        SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager,
        ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> ProfileView()
    {
        var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
        if (user == null)
        {
            return NotFound($"Unable to load user with ID '{_userManager.GetUserId(User)}'.");
        }
        return View(user);
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ProfileView(ApplicationUser users)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View();
        }

        var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
        if (user == null)
        {
            return NotFound($"Unable to load user with ID '{_userManager.GetUserId(User)}'.");
        }

        user.FirstName = users.FirstName;
        user.LastName = users.LastName;

        _context.Users.Update(user);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        await _signInManager.RefreshSignInAsync(user);
        return RedirectToAction();
    }
}
```